# host MS Bot Framework Composer c# project in self-hosted service

Tags: botframework

In v3 we had option to host c# project in Windows Service. I can't found any examples of it.
How we can do same with MS BOT Composer c# project?

Comment: I'm not aware of what is needed to implement this, but I did want to point out you can implement composer in a docker container. This _is_ the better place for how-to questions, but If you think there should be guidance or implementation put in place to make this possible, you can create a DCR/enhancement/feature request issue in the composer repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Composer

Comment: We use windows service to host bot.  Before test it in windows service I decided to use Composer output in IISExpress host: I create new empty project and just added simple response on beginning, then  tried to open Composer output from BotFramework-Composer\MyBots\  folder and open it in VS 2017. It compiled correct but then when I tried to debug it in IISExpress I got below error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'BotProject'.
Check that the project for 'BotProject' has set the 'UserSecretsId' build property.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/1654) is the thread you will want to keep an eye on. Please feel free to add input and suggestions there.

Comment: this thread is about to host Composer in IIS. My question is about how to host bot created by C# or composer in windows service?

Comment: Sorry about that. Posting in your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095663/how-host-ms-bot-created-in-c-sharp-or-composer-in-windows-service