# How to host ms bot created in c# or composer in windows service?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

We must use C# MS bot in windows service. How to implement it in .Net core for MSBot SDKv4?
All samples using IIS/Azure App service as hosting platform.

Answer (score 0):

They're aren't any examples or samples that show how to explicitly do this. But you should be able to follow articles such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) or [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/21/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-app-as-a-windows-service-in-net-core-3/) and then tweak as needed. It shouldn't be much different than hosting any other asp.net core application.

The two points to make sure and cover are:

1. Make sure that the bot/application is configured (whether in appsettings.json or otherwise) so that it has the right configuration data. Specifically appid/password
2. Ensure the endpoint can be hit by the connector/channels.